# Javascript timepicker range update

Tags: javascript, datepicker, timepicker

I'm using this timepicker http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

When user first time select date from **datepicker** then i get data from server and put them into array in right format. This array i use for **timepicker** in **disableTimeRanges**. That works when user click first time but when user change date second time then disableTimeRanges wont update so it stay same as first time.

Is there way to "reset" timepicker when user click on datepicker?

Here is a code:

```
$("#datefrom").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: function (date) {
       $.post("ajax-date-check.php", {'date': date}, function(result){

            var ret = result.replace(/"/g,'');
            var length = ret.length; 
            var string = ret.slice(1, length-1);
            var array = JSON
            .parse('[' + string.replace(/'/g, '"') + ']')
       .reduce((r, s, i) => r.concat([i % 2 ? r.pop().concat(s) : [s]]), 
        []);

        $('.timepicker1').timepicker({
            'timeFormat': 'H:i',
            'minTime': '8:00am',
            'maxTime': '8:00pm',
            'disableTimeRanges': array,
            'show2400': true
        });
  });

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why your array declare inside of $.post()?

try this

```
$("#datefrom").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: async function (date) {
       var array;
       await $.post("ajax-date-check.php", {'date': date}, function(result){

            var ret = result.replace(/"/g,'');
            var length = ret.length; 
            var string = ret.slice(1, length-1);
            array = JSON
            .parse('[' + string.replace(/'/g, '"') + ']')
       .reduce((r, s, i) => r.concat([i % 2 ? r.pop().concat(s) : [s]]), 
        []);

        $('.timepicker1').timepicker({
            'timeFormat': 'H:i',
            'minTime': '8:00am',
            'maxTime': '8:00pm',
            'disableTimeRanges': array,
            'show2400': true
        });
  });

  }
});
```

Comment: it's a same thing.

Comment: @user3590094 try use async and await. I update the answer.